# datasets.load_iris() in Python

Tags: python, dataset

What does the function `load_iris()` do ?
Also, I don't understand what type of data it contains and where to find it.

```
iris = datasets.load_iris() 
X = iris.data 
target = iris.target 
names = iris.target_names
```

Can somebody please tell in detail what does this piece of code does?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`load_iris`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html) is a function from `sklearn`. The link provides documentation: `iris` in your code will be a dictionary-like object. `X` and `y` will be `numpy` arrays, and `names` has the array of possible targets as text (rather than numeric values as in `y`).

Comment: Can you give an example ?

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: I need to use another data, but I can't load it, instead of iris, so I want to know how this works.

Comment: Have you looked at [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_iris.html)? `load_iris` is a custom function for this particular, [well-known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iris_flower_data_set) dataset. If you're using your own data, you'll likely need to use a function like [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) from pandas, then specify a set of columns as `X` and `y`. Did I understand what you're asking?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it really helped

Answer (score 7):

You can get some documentation with:

```
# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()

print('The data matrix:\n',iris['data'])
print('The classification target:\n',iris['target'])
print('The names of the dataset columns:\n',iris['feature_names'])
print('The names of target classes:\n',iris['target_names'])
print('The full description of the dataset:\n',iris['DESCR'])
print('The path to the location of the data:\n',iris['filename'])
```

This gives you:

- The data matrix:

```
 [[5.1 3.5 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.  1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [4.6 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.6 1.4 0.2]
 [5.4 3.9 1.7 0.4]
 [4.6 3.4 1.4 0.3]
 [5.  3.4 1.5 0.2]
 [4.4 2.9 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.1 1.5 0.1]
 [5.4 3.7 1.5 0.2]
 [4.8 3.4 1.6 0.2]
 [4.8 3.  1.4 0.1]
 [4.3 3.  1.1 0.1]
 [5.8 4.  1.2 0.2]
 [5.7 4.4 1.5 0.4]
 [5.4 3.9 1.3 0.4]
 [5.1 3.5 1.4 0.3]
 [5.7 3.8 1.7 0.3]
 [5.1 3.8 1.5 0.3]
 [5.4 3.4 1.7 0.2]
 [5.1 3.7 1.5 0.4]
 [4.6 3.6 1.  0.2]
 [5.1 3.3 1.7 0.5]
 [4.8 3.4 1.9 0.2]
 [5.  3.  1.6 0.2]
 [5.  3.4 1.6 0.4]
 [5.2 3.5 1.5 0.2]
 [5.2 3.4 1.4 0.2]
 [4.7 3.2 1.6 0.2]
 [4.8 3.1 1.6 0.2]
 [5.4 3.4 1.5 0.4]
 [5.2 4.1 1.5 0.1]
 [5.5 4.2 1.4 0.2]
 [4.9 3.1 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.2 1.2 0.2]
 [5.5 3.5 1.3 0.2]
 [4.9 3.6 1.4 0.1]
 [4.4 3.  1.3 0.2]
 [5.1 3.4 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.5 1.3 0.3]
 [4.5 2.3 1.3 0.3]
 [4.4 3.2 1.3 0.2]
 [5.  3.5 1.6 0.6]
 [5.1 3.8 1.9 0.4]
 [4.8 3.  1.4 0.3]
 [5.1 3.8 1.6 0.2]
 [4.6 3.2 1.4 0.2]
 [5.3 3.7 1.5 0.2]
 [5.  3.3 1.4 0.2]
 [7.  3.2 4.7 1.4]
 [6.4 3.2 4.5 1.5]
 [6.9 3.1 4.9 1.5]
 [5.5 2.3 4.  1.3]
 [6.5 2.8 4.6 1.5]
 [5.7 2.8 4.5 1.3]
 [6.3 3.3 4.7 1.6]
 [4.9 2.4 3.3 1. ]
 [6.6 2.9 4.6 1.3]
 [5.2 2.7 3.9 1.4]
 [5.  2.  3.5 1. ]
 [5.9 3.  4.2 1.5]
 [6.  2.2 4.  1. ]
 [6.1 2.9 4.7 1.4]
 [5.6 2.9 3.6 1.3]
 [6.7 3.1 4.4 1.4]
 [5.6 3.  4.5 1.5]
 [5.8 2.7 4.1 1. ]
 [6.2 2.2 4.5 1.5]
 [5.6 2.5 3.9 1.1]
 [5.9 3.2 4.8 1.8]
 [6.1 2.8 4.  1.3]
 [6.3 2.5 4.9 1.5]
 [6.1 2.8 4.7 1.2]
 [6.4 2.9 4.3 1.3]
 [6.6 3.  4.4 1.4]
 [6.8 2.8 4.8 1.4]
 [6.7 3.  5.  1.7]
 [6.  2.9 4.5 1.5]
 [5.7 2.6 3.5 1. ]
 [5.5 2.4 3.8 1.1]
 [5.5 2.4 3.7 1. ]
 [5.8 2.7 3.9 1.2]
 [6.  2.7 5.1 1.6]
 [5.4 3.  4.5 1.5]
 [6.  3.4 4.5 1.6]
 [6.7 3.1 4.7 1.5]
 [6.3 2.3 4.4 1.3]
 [5.6 3.  4.1 1.3]
 [5.5 2.5 4.  1.3]
 [5.5 2.6 4.4 1.2]
 [6.1 3.  4.6 1.4]
 [5.8 2.6 4.  1.2]
 [5.  2.3 3.3 1. ]
 [5.6 2.7 4.2 1.3]
 [5.7 3.  4.2 1.2]
 [5.7 2.9 4.2 1.3]
 [6.2 2.9 4.3 1.3]
 [5.1 2.5 3.  1.1]
 [5.7 2.8 4.1 1.3]
 [6.3 3.3 6.  2.5]
 [5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9]
 [7.1 3.  5.9 2.1]
 [6.3 2.9 5.6 1.8]
 [6.5 3.  5.8 2.2]
 [7.6 3.  6.6 2.1]
 [4.9 2.5 4.5 1.7]
 [7.3 2.9 6.3 1.8]
 [6.7 2.5 5.8 1.8]
 [7.2 3.6 6.1 2.5]
 [6.5 3.2 5.1 2. ]
 [6.4 2.7 5.3 1.9]
 [6.8 3.  5.5 2.1]
 [5.7 2.5 5.  2. ]
 [5.8 2.8 5.1 2.4]
 [6.4 3.2 5.3 2.3]
 [6.5 3.  5.5 1.8]
 [7.7 3.8 6.7 2.2]
 [7.7 2.6 6.9 2.3]
 [6.  2.2 5.  1.5]
 [6.9 3.2 5.7 2.3]
 [5.6 2.8 4.9 2. ]
 [7.7 2.8 6.7 2. ]
 [6.3 2.7 4.9 1.8]
 [6.7 3.3 5.7 2.1]
 [7.2 3.2 6.  1.8]
 [6.2 2.8 4.8 1.8]
 [6.1 3.  4.9 1.8]
 [6.4 2.8 5.6 2.1]
 [7.2 3.  5.8 1.6]
 [7.4 2.8 6.1 1.9]
 [7.9 3.8 6.4 2. ]
 [6.4 2.8 5.6 2.2]
 [6.3 2.8 5.1 1.5]
 [6.1 2.6 5.6 1.4]
 [7.7 3.  6.1 2.3]
 [6.3 3.4 5.6 2.4]
 [6.4 3.1 5.5 1.8]
 [6.  3.  4.8 1.8]
 [6.9 3.1 5.4 2.1]
 [6.7 3.1 5.6 2.4]
 [6.9 3.1 5.1 2.3]
 [5.8 2.7 5.1 1.9]
 [6.8 3.2 5.9 2.3]
 [6.7 3.3 5.7 2.5]
 [6.7 3.  5.2 2.3]
 [6.3 2.5 5.  1.9]
 [6.5 3.  5.2 2. ]
 [6.2 3.4 5.4 2.3]
 [5.9 3.  5.1 1.8]]
```

- The classification target:

```
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 2 2]
```

- The names of the dataset columns:

```
 ['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']
```

- The names of target classes:

```
 ['setosa' 'versicolor' 'virginica']
```

- The full description of the dataset:

> .. _iris_dataset:
>
> Iris plants dataset
>
> ---
>
> **Data Set Characteristics:**
>
> ```
> :Number of Instances: 150 (50 in each of three classes)
> :Number of Attributes: 4 numeric, predictive attributes and the class
> :Attribute Information:
>     - sepal length in cm
>     - sepal width in cm
>     - petal length in cm
>     - petal width in cm
>     - class:
>             - Iris-Setosa
>             - Iris-Versicolour
>             - Iris-Virginica
>             
> :Summary Statistics:
>
> ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================
>                 Min  Max   Mean    SD   Class Correlation
> ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================
> sepal length:   4.3  7.9   5.84   0.83    0.7826
> sepal width:    2.0  4.4   3.05   0.43   -0.4194
> petal length:   1.0  6.9   3.76   1.76    0.9490  (high!)
> petal width:    0.1  2.5   1.20   0.76    0.9565  (high!)
> ============== ==== ==== ======= ===== ====================
>
> :Missing Attribute Values: None
> :Class Distribution: 33.3% for each of 3 classes.
> :Creator: R.A. Fisher
> :Donor: Michael Marshall (MARSHALL%PLU@io.arc.nasa.gov)
> :Date: July, 1988
> ```
>
> The famous Iris database, first used by Sir R.A. Fisher. The dataset is taken
> from Fisher's paper. Note that it's the same as in R, but not as in the UCI
> Machine Learning Repository, which has two wrong data points.
>
> This is perhaps the best known database to be found in the
> pattern recognition literature.  Fisher's paper is a classic in the field and
> is referenced frequently to this day.  (See Duda & Hart, for example.)  The
> data set contains 3 classes of 50 instances each, where each class refers to a
> type of iris plant.  One class is linearly separable from the other 2; the
> latter are NOT linearly separable from each other.
>
> .. topic:: References
>
> - Fisher, R.A. "The use of multiple measurements in taxonomic problems"
>   Annual Eugenics, 7, Part II, 179-188 (1936); also in "Contributions to
>   Mathematical Statistics" (John Wiley, NY, 1950).
> - Duda, R.O., & Hart, P.E. (1973) Pattern Classification and Scene Analysis.
>   (Q327.D83) John Wiley & Sons.  ISBN 0-471-22361-1.  See page 218.
> - Dasarathy, B.V. (1980) "Nosing Around the Neighborhood: A New System
>   Structure and Classification Rule for Recognition in Partially Exposed
>   Environments".  IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine
>   Intelligence, Vol. PAMI-2, No. 1, 67-71.
> - Gates, G.W. (1972) "The Reduced Nearest Neighbor Rule".  IEEE Transactions
>   on Information Theory, May 1972, 431-433.
> - See also: 1988 MLC Proceedings, 54-64.  Cheeseman et al"s AUTOCLASS II
>   conceptual clustering system finds 3 classes in the data.
> - Many, many more ...

- The path to the location of the data:

/Applications/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/datasets/data/iris.csv

Answer (score 4):

To thread off the previous comments and posts from above, wanted to add another way to load iris() besides `iris = datasets.load_iris()`

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
```

Then, you can do:

```
X = iris.data 
target = iris.target 
names = iris.target_names
```

And see posts and comments from other people here.

And you can make a dataframe with :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X, columns=iris.feature_names)
df['species'] = iris.target
df['species'] = df['species'].replace(to_replace= [0, 1, 2], value = ['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'])
```